# Cannot access Javascript property

Tags: javascript

Below function fails with `Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`.
Why is the method `message` undefined?

```
function person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.message = function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old !");
    }

};

person("nirmesh", 35).message();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do an OOP approach, right ? meaning that `person(name, age)` is supposed to be a constructor.

In that case, you're forgetting the `new` keyword to instantiate a new object like so : `(new person("nirmesh",35)).message();`

PS: You don't really need the wrapping brackets, it's more for elaboration :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an *object* of *person* with the ***new*** keyword and by passing the *parameter*. Then call the function on that *object*:

```js
function person(name, age) {
    this.name = name,
    this.age = age,
    this.message = function () {
        console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old !");
    }

};
var p = new person("nirmesh",35);
p.message();
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling person function does not return anything. If you want to access person function after calling it you should return it:

```
function person(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.message = function () {
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old !");
        }
return this;
    };

    person("nirmesh",35).message();
```

However, I am not sure if the way you are doing this is right!